# ошибка при загрузке пакета devtools для R

Tags: github, r, rstudio

Прошу консультации по загрузке пакета devtools для R studio.
Установил пакет через официальный репозиторий CRAN. Пакет обновлений не требует.
Команда library("devtools") возвращает сообщение:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘fs’.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, что делать в этой ситуации.
P/S Данный пакет мне нужен для загрузки пакета install_github("bdemeshev/rlms") - никак не удается его загрузить.

Comment: `there is no package called ‘fs’` — вероятно, надо поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо поставить покет fs

there is no package called ‘fs’ - нет пакета под названием "fs"